# Button onClick jquery not working in safari, iPhone

Tags: jquery, onclick, mobile-safari

My Button code is this

```
<input class="submitBtn2" type="button" value="Nulstil adgangskode" onclick="FnFForGetPassword(); return false;">
```

My function is this

```
function FnFForGetPassword() {

        if ($('#txtFnFEmail').val() == '') {
                $("#EmailErrRequired").html("Email-feltet er påkrævet").show();

                return false;
            }else{
    ...continue...
```

Its working on chrome and android devices but not working on safari and iPhone devices.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your input tag to this:

```
<input class="submitBtn2" type="button" value="Nulstil adgangskode" onclick="javascript:FnFForGetPassword()" />
```